# Basic server taking up massive CPU resources- how to alleviate?

Tags: c++, multithreading, server

I'm writing a pretty basic server in C++.

I've ended up with an architecture similar to this:

One thread (the server) is constantly looping over `accept()` waiting for connections [(docs)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/accept).

Every connection it finds, it spawns a thread that loops over `recv()` waiting for something to read, and `send()` that sends out anything in its queue [(recv docs)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recv), [(send docs)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/send).

However, I want to be able to (from an external thread) tell either the server or individual connections to essentially kill themselves. The problem is that `accept()` and `recv()` both block until they find any activity, so there's no way for them to check if their `should_kill_self` member is set or anything. So to fix that, I called `fcntl(sock_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)` on the file descriptors so that they won't.

This way, I have the server constantly looping over `accept()` and checking `should_kill_self`, and I have each connection looping over `recv()`, check if anything in queue to `send()`, and checking `should_kill_self`.

So this way, I can signal them to kill themselves at any time, but a side effect I've noticed is that they are taking up huge amounts of processing. I am wondering if with this setup I'm doing something stupid resulting in redundant computation. I don't need this to be a super-low-latency server AT ALL, so is the "correct" way to alleviate this by like, sleeping for 10 seconds between every loop?

I'm new to writing networking code, so I'm pretty sure I'm just doing something stupid. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The correct way is to use select or poll.

Comment: Use `select`, and *don't* spawn a thread for each incoming connection--instead when a connection comes in, push something onto a (thread-safe) queue, and have a small pool of threads, each of which grabs an item from the queue, processes, and repeats.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to explore non-blocking IO in Linux or IO completion ports on windows. See [here](http://www.kegel.com/dkftpbench/nonblocking.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O).

Programming these needs extra effort and is abit harder than programming the simple socket server. However, there are libraries that will wrap non-blocking IO (and IOCP) and provides a simple interface for you to use. One example being ASIO in boost. There are many other libraries even for Java and other languages.